# Why is Fore.BLUE making the text start with random characters instead of making the text blue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, colorama

Here is my code:

```
from colorama import Fore
print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello")
```

I expect the output to be the word "Hello" with the color blue, but instead the output is

```
(?)[34mHello
```

except replace (?) with ? surrounded by a square. Is there something wrong with my code? If so, how do I fix it?

I am using Python 3.7.4 if that means anything

Edit: I also want to do the same thing except with input instead of print

Comment: That's the escape character for blue in a terminal. It sounds like your terminal doesn't support escape characters to change colours.

Comment: (blueteeth: that is the exact purpose of `colorama`: enable ANSI sequences on Windows CMD - but apparently, the OP forgot to initialize the lib, which works by wrapping `sys.stdout`  and placing calls to windows APIs to change colors instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not "random character" - these are the character that form the ANSI control sequence to change the foreground to Blue, and what people see on WIndows `cmd` when trying to display colors without using colorama.

It looks like you just forgot to call `colorama.init()` prior to try to use the ANSI sequences.

Do:

```py
import colorama

from colorama import Fore

colorama.init()

print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello")
```

Comment: This does work with print. Sorry I forgot to put this in the post, but I also need input to work with colorama. If I do this exact script except replace ```print(Fore.BLUE + "Hello")``` with ```input(Fore.BLUE + "Hello")``` it does the ANSI thing again. Do you know how I would fix this?

Comment: if you put the `.init` call before calling `input` it should just work.